# How to apply classification on series data in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

The structure of my input data is:

```
print(df.col)
```

```python
0    [262, 330, 392, 522, 784, 0, 0]
1    [262, 290, 330, 392, 522, 784, 0]
2    [262, 330, 392, 522, 784, 0, 0]
3    [250, 262, 330, 392, 522, 784, 0]
4    [262, 290, 306, 330, 392, 784, 0]
.
.
.
```

I had variable sized data so I've added a padding of 0's in the end to fix the input data shape.

The output column is:

```python
print(df.predict)

array([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],...])
```

Output is one hot encoded.

Following is my model:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(7, activation='relu', input_dim = 7))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, batch_size=10,  verbose=2)
```

The accuracy and loss become constant after 2-3 epochs.

```python
Epoch 1/500
0s - loss: 5.8413 - acc: 0.1754
Epoch 2/500
0s - loss: 5.7398 - acc: 0.1754
Epoch 3/500
0s - loss: 5.7190 - acc: 0.1754
Epoch 4/500
0s - loss: 5.6885 - acc: 0.1754
Epoch 5/500
0s - loss: 5.6650 - acc: 0.1754
Epoch 6/500
0s - loss: 5.6403 - acc: 0.1754
Epoch 7/500
0s - loss: 5.6164 - acc: 0.2456
Epoch 8/500
0s - loss: 5.5900 - acc: 0.2456
Epoch 9/500
0s - loss: 5.5730 - acc: 0.2456
...
0s - loss: 5.3727 - acc: 0.1754
Epoch 499/500
0s - loss: 5.3727 - acc: 0.1754
Epoch 500/500
0s - loss: 5.3727 - acc: 0.1754
```

I have 72 data points and 4 classes (about 18 samples for each class)
The data is fairly simple. Why is the accuracy so low?

Is the model designed right?
I'm new to ML and Keras. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using a linear activation for a classification problem is terrible, try changing the final layer's activation to softmax and report on the results ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation = 'softmax'))` as you last layer.

If you have more than 2 classes for classification you will need a softmax layer in the end. This is a function, that output the probabilities for the 4 different classes (all add to 1) and the one with the highest probability will be your class. This way your network will be able to learn all the 4 different classes instead of only two.

Comment: The accuracy changes each time I run the model. I tried softmax, but I'm still getting constant poor accuracy. Epoch 1/1000
0s - loss: 12.8945 - acc: 0.2000
Epoch 2/1000
0s - loss: 12.8945 - acc: 0.2000
Epoch 3/1000
0s - loss: 12.8945 - acc: 0.2000
Epoch 4/1000
0s - loss: 12.8945 - acc: 0.2000
Epoch 5/1000
0s - loss: 12.8945 - acc: 0.2000
Epoch 6/1000
0s - loss: 12.8945 - acc: 0.2000